# Docker Compose postgres db does not start

Tags: postgresql, docker

Hello for some reason my postgres keeps restarting basically this is my docker compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    container_name: "db"
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}

  api:
    image: server_emasa
    container_name: api
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}"
```

and for some reason my postgres is restarting I tried using the docker compose logs to check and got this:

```
db     | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db     | 
db     | 2020-03-26 05:37:18.475 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Debian 12.2-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db     | 2020-03-26 05:37:18.475 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db     | 2020-03-26 05:37:18.475 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db     | 2020-03-26 05:37:18.558 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db     | 2020-03-26 05:37:18.625 UTC [1] LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory
db     | 2020-03-26 05:37:18.646 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-03-23 23:46:31 UTC
db     | 2020-03-26 05:37:18.879 UTC [26] LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory
db     | 2020-03-26 05:37:18.879 UTC [26] LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory
db     | 2020-03-26 05:37:18.879 UTC [26] FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_replslot": No such file or directory
db     | 2020-03-26 05:37:18.880 UTC [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 26) exited with exit code 1
db     | 2020-03-26 05:37:18.880 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
db     | 2020-03-26 05:37:18.881 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error refers to postgresql not being able to find critical files, but is not attempting to create them because your `pgdata` directory contains some files.

Try not to bind your `pgdata` directory to the docker container, just remove the `volumes` section in your docker-compose file

Comment: I didn't understand, could you explain it better? Would I need to remove my volume from the docker-compose?

Comment: Docker containers have their own disk space, there is no need to share a volume between your local machine and the container.

Comment: You are not correct. You sometime need to persist data, that's why we sometimes need to bind docker volume to local disk space

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem after restarting my postgresql container:

```
LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc/memory/...": Not a directory
```

The reason of the error is probably because of [data corruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_corruption#:%7E:text=Data%20corruption%20refers%20to%20errors,integrity%2C%20or%20lack%20of%20errors.) in database.

You can solve the issue by deleting contents of pg_tblspc/ directory (make sure to backup all of them) or you can also try by recovering the latest backup of your database (if there's one).

Answer (score 0):

first remove associated docker volume and data folder then:
POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME} will not work, use like this:

```
 environment:
   - 'POSTGRES_DB=med_db'
   - 'POSTGRES_USER:postgres'
   - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD:pass'
```